# how to use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to deserialize multiple date format

Tags: java, date, jackson

My POST/PUT request input contains 2 types of date format as string with following format: 
1) 2000-09-15T08:15:30-05:00
2) 2000-09-15T13:15:30Z

I need to deserialize both format but serialize only to zulu format. Shall I write a deserializer to do this? Or there is any annotation I can use to set?

for serialization, I have already had following settings in Java:

```
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
builder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
builder.indentOutput(true);
builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using global default configuration, what you need is to use `@JsonFormat(pattern="date-format-pattern")` for each field that does not use defaults.

Comment: I need to use default format for all serialization and accept both format in deserialization.  So this should be a global setting, not per field. Thanks

Comment: @YHC Good luck with that then!